# Subsetting and transposing table iterating in R

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, transpose, cbind

I have this table (**inputdf**):

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 |
| 1 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.7 |
| 3 | 0.1 |

and I want to obtain this (**outputdf**):

| Number1 | Number2 | Number3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| 0.3 | 0.7 | NA |
| 0.4 | NA | NA |

I have tried it by iterating with a for loop through the numbers in column 1, then subsetting the dataframe by that number but I have troubles to append the result to an output dataframe:

```
inputdf <- read.table("input.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)
outputdf <- data.frame()

i=1
total=3 ###user has to modify it

for(i in seq(1:total)) {
  cat("Collecting values for number", i, "\n")
  values <- subset(input, Number == i, select=c(Value))
  cbind(outputdf, NewColumn= values, )
  names(outputdf)[names(outputdf) == "NewColumn"] <- paste0("Number", i)
}
```

Any help or hint will be very wellcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think my problems are that the columns do not have the same number of values.

Answer (score 1):

In the `tidyverse`, you can create an id for each element of the groups and then use `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  group_by(Number) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Number, names_prefix = "Number", values_from = "Value")

# A tibble: 3 × 4
      n Number1 Number2 Number3
  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     0.2     0.2     0.1
2     2     0.3     0.7    NA  
3     3     0.4    NA      NA
```

---

in `base R`, same idea. Create the `id` column and then reshape to wide:

```r
transform(dat, id = with(dat, ave(rep(1, nrow(dat)), Number, FUN = seq_along))) |>
  reshape(direction = "wide", timevar = "Number")
```